# Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, magento-1.6

I am developing a custom module where an xml file will be created after order completion for each order.

I have called a function exportOrder on occuring of an event "sales_order_place_after". Following is the code of my function

```
public function exportOrder($order){
    $dirPath = Mage::getBaseDir('var').DS.'export';

    //if the export directory does not exist, create it
    if (!is_dir($dirPath)) {
         mkdir($dirPath, 0777, true);
    }

    $data = $order->getData();

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
    array_walk_recursive($data, array ($xml, 'addChild'));

    file_put_contents(
        $dirPath.DS.$order->getIncrementId().'.xml',
        $xml->asXML()
    );
```

Now here on line no 12 ie: `$data->getData();` I am getting an error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /home/user_www/aliasgar/magentotesting/app/code/local/Meteorify/Observerexample/Model/Export.php on line 12

My config.xml is as follows

```
<global>
<helpers>
    <orderexport>
        <class>Meteorify_Observerexample_Helper</class>
    </orderexport>
</helpers>
<models>
    <meteorify_observerexample>
         <class>Meteorify_Observerexample_Model</class>
    </meteorify_observerexample>
</models>
<events>
  <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    <observers>
      <sales_order_place_after>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>Meteorify_Observerexample_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>exportOrder</method>
      </sales_order_place_after>
    </observers>
  </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>     
</events>
```

This is how my Observer.php file looks

```
class Meteorify_Observerexample_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object{

public function exportOrder($observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    Mage::log($order);
    Mage::getModel('meteorify_observerexample/export')->exportOrder($order);
    return true;
}
```

}

I am not able to figure out the mistake. Please help me in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the event incorrectly.

In event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

the order is not sent as an object, but as the order id. (as order_ids)

`Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));`

(ref `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::successAction`)

Thus in your observer you need to get the id, as such:

```
$orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds(); // returns an array 
$orderId = array_shift($orderIds);
```

and instantiate the order object using

```
$order = mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
```

(the above written off the top of my head, but the jest of it should be correct)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Now i am getting the value of orderId using `$orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();` and placed $order = mage::getModel('sales/order')->getId($orderId);' but still the problem prevails. The error i am getting is `Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /home/user_www/aliasgar/magentotesting/app/code/local/Meteorify/Observerexample/Model/Export.php on line 11` I am not getting is there any mistake in xml file?

Comment: Also `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getId($orderId);` using var_dump gives me NULL value for this line of code

Comment: note the edit in my answer - use ->load($orderId) and not getId() - a typo/mistake ;)

Comment: also note further edits. Note that the value of order_ids is an array of values, thus can receive multiple order ids. You'll need to code to accomodate for such an instance. The code given shoudl get you on the right track, and is untested.

Comment: also, in the future, if you use an observer/event, and you get stuck, the simplest way forward is to grep the core code for code that uses the same event. Thus first grep for the event name, which will yield the config.xml where it is defined, and from that you will get the model/method. Then you can peek at the core code to see what is done in the event. You can also grep for where the event is fired, to see what values are passed.

Answer (score 3):

In your observer you don't get the `$order` directly, you need to get it from the observer parameter like this:

```
public function exportOrder($observer){
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $data = $order->getData();
```

Comment: @Vladmir Kerkhoff: In my function exportOrder($order), in the file Export.php here $order as passed in exportOrder from Observer.php is `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();`. Is it necessary to redeclare it ?

Comment: Check my file Observer.php `public function exportOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
  Mage::getModel('meteorify_observerexample/export')->exportOrder($order);
  return true;
    }`

Comment: No, this should work then. You can try to do a Mage::log($order) in the observer file to check what data you receive.

Comment: I'll try out the log then

Comment: This is what i am getting in log `2013-08-12T12:57:16+00:00 DEBUG (7):` and using var_dump i am getting NULL value.